# Does completeness of $L(E,F)$ implies completeness of $F$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $E$ and $F$ be two normed spaces with $E \neq \{0\}$  and $L(E,F)$, the set of all bounded linear maps from $E$ to $F$ is complete normed space under the operator norm .

Is $F$  complete?

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ Obviously, the converse is true . And I was thinking of $E = \mathbb R$ and $F = \mathbb{P}[0,1]$, set of polynomials on $[0,1]$, under supremum norm ; where $F$ is not complete, but I can't conclude about $L(E,F)$.

A small hint is warmly appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

Let $(f_n)$ be a  Cauchy sequence in $F$. Let $x^{*}$ be any non-zero continuous linear functional on $E$. Define $T_n: E \to F$ by $T_n x=x^{*}(x) f_n$. Show that $\|T_n-T_m\|=\|x^{*} \| \|f_n-f_m\|$. So $(T_n)$ converges to some operator $T$. Now pick any $x$ such that $x^{*}(x)\neq 0$ and use convergence of  $x^{*}(x) f_n $ to see that $(f_n)$ converges.